# Adding data to Data model with variable range within the workbook

Tags: excel, vba, variables, pivot-table, datamodel

I have a question. How can I use a variable in this Data Model when my source data is within my workbook, but the range of the data is going to be different every month and I am not using a Table format of the data but a normal range. My code looks like this:
My concern is also about the quotation marks and ampersands or is there any other way I can incorporate the address or range of my data range?

Any response is highly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried to get the distinct count information from my data set with the help of Data Model however I wasn't able to write the appropriate code specially the dynamic range in the argument section. I would like to know if I can use relative or absolute references or some other variable for the data range definition.

Here is the code:

```
`Dim myrange As String
myrange = Sheets("EKPO").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address

Workbooks("Book1").Connections.Add2 "WorksheetConnection_EKPO!" & myrange,
, "", "WORKSHEET;\[Book1\]EKPO!" & myrange, "EKPO!" & myrange, 7, True, False
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:=
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("WorksheetConnection_EKPO!" & myrange), Version
:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Data model!R1C1", TableName:=
"PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=8`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite complex and I'll try to answer to each part of it.

1. Always been good for me to concatenate data with "&" . Thus, you could use variable priorly initialized to store the value for easier debugging. Also, if your range is always the same, you can also fix it using 'EKPO!A1' without using address, directly in your connections strings.
2. You can absolutely use both relative or absolute references. Personally, I prefer using absolute when I can, and I manage to make my sheet as clean as possible so my absolute references are kept untouched. Using relative references is quite powerful, therefore, if any change happen to your sheet (likely to happen if shared), then your references will move and stange behaviour can happen.

Maybe if you have a precise use case to share, I could answer more precisely to your questions.